# Blue bubble of current location in google maps not showing during first attempt in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am creating an android app having google maps.I want to show the current location as the default blue dot with the current location button.The blue dot and the button is shown fine on a newer version of android.But on a older device ,it is not shown on the first running of the app but is fine from the second attempt.I have tried using android support library but to no avail.

The code i have used is shown below:

```
public void getcurrentlocation()
    {
         locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null)
        {
            current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
           current_longitude = location.getLongitude();
           initialiseMap();
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        }
public void initialiseMap()
    {
        if (googleMap == null) {
             googleMap = ( (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();


       }
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else
        {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
//          UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
//          uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);



            }
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(current_latitude, current_longitude);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        //googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12f));
        new RetrieveStoreDetails().execute();
        }
```

Is there a workaround to show the blue dot from the beginning itself on the older version(2.6) of android.Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Blue dot appearance depends on your device being able to localize itself.

**Make sure you turn on the GPS and have related settings enabled in My location part of Settings app**: "Use wireless networks" and "Use GPS satellites".

Comment: Use wirelss networks,Use GPS setellites and use sensor aiding are on in the settings.Still i am getting the problem.Any other suggestions?